# accessing external .net DLL from own .net 4.6.1 c# interop DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, interop, powerbuilder

I need to modify my existing DLL in c# to interface between PowerBuilder 2017 (PB) and an external DLL developed by vendor.  external.DLL is using .net 4.6.1

PB Target <-> my.DLL <-> external.DLL

I have set my.DLL up to be COM Interop enabled (Make assembly COM-Visible + Register for COM interop) and have previously set this to work in PB IDE without 'external.DLL' just fine by applying following commands:

- regasm my.DLL
- gacutil my.DLL (this is used only so PowerBuilder can access the DLL from within it's IDE)

Now, I try and reference external.DLL through my.DLL from PowerBuilder IDE I receive an error -3 code (Object could not be created).

How am I best to setup and also distribute both DLL files?

I think my issue is in setting up the References within Visual Studio 2017.

The COM interop is needed between PB and my.DLL.
I tried to add a follow Debug option as this would be helpful, but cannot trigger it.

Comment: Make sure you can debug any exceptions thrown by your C# code.  Project > Properties > Debug tab, Start external program radio button.  A common mishap is that the CLR will not be able to find that "external DLL".

Comment: if the external dll is developed with .net then you don't need interop COM. Just add reference to the dll and you are good to go. Use it like its part of your project

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help.
I managed to get my.DLL working inside PowerBuilder IDE by using regasm on the external.dll and adding it also into the GAC.
For deployment of the PowerBuilder Application I expect to apply regasm to both DLL's and place them in same distribution folder.